# Keyboard navigation with list item not working properly?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I am create a dropdown component with keyboard navigation

`hook`

```
export const useKeyPress = function (targetKey: string) {
    const [keyPressed, setKeyPressed] = React.useState(false);

    function downHandler({ key }: { key: string }) {
        if (key === targetKey) {
            setKeyPressed(true);
        }
    }

    const upHandler = ({ key }: { key: string }) => {
        if (key === targetKey) {
            setKeyPressed(false);
        }
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("keydown", downHandler);
        window.addEventListener("keyup", upHandler);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("keydown", downHandler);
            window.removeEventListener("keyup", upHandler);
        };
    });

    return keyPressed;
};
```

And in my compoennt-

```
const downPress = useKeyPress("ArrowDown");
const upPress = useKeyPress("ArrowUp");
const enterPress = useKeyPress("Enter");
useEffect(() => {
        if (countryDataInfo.length && downPress) {
            setCursor(prevState =>
                prevState < countryDataInfo.length - 1 ? prevState + 1 : prevState
            );
        }
    }, [downPress]);
useEffect(() => {
        if (countryDataInfo.length && upPress) {
            setCursor(prevState => (prevState > 0 ? prevState - 1 : prevState));
        }
    }, [upPress]);
useEffect(() => {
        if (countryDataInfo.length && enterPress) {
            setSelected(countryDataInfo[cursor]);
        }
    }, [cursor, enterPress]);



<ul className={isDropdown ? "simple-phone-input-sri198-dropdown active" : "simple-phone-input-sri198-dropdown"} >
    {search &&
        <div className="simple-phone-input-sri198-search-container">
            <input
                placeholder={searchPlaceholder}
                {...searchProps}
                onChange={onSearchHandler}
            />
            {showSearchIcon &&
                <div className="simple-phone-input-sri198-search-icon">
                    {searchIconComponent ?? (
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1em" height="1em" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 48 48"><g fill="#616161"><path d="m29.175 31.99l2.828-2.827l12.019 12.019l-2.828 2.827z" /><circle cx="20" cy="20" r="16" /></g><path fill="#37474F" d="m32.45 35.34l2.827-2.828l8.696 8.696l-2.828 2.828z" /><circle cx="20" cy="20" r="13" fill="#64B5F6" /><path fill="#BBDEFB" d="M26.9 14.2c-1.7-2-4.2-3.2-6.9-3.2s-5.2 1.2-6.9 3.2c-.4.4-.3 1.1.1 1.4c.4.4 1.1.3 1.4-.1C16 13.9 17.9 13 20 13s4 .9 5.4 2.5c.2.2.5.4.8.4c.2 0 .5-.1.6-.2c.4-.4.4-1.1.1-1.5z" /></svg>
                    )}

                </div>
            }
        </div>
    }
    {countryDataInfo.length === 0 &&
        <div className="simple-phone-input-sri198-not-found">
            {searchNotFound}
        </div>
    }
    {countryDataInfo.map((item, i) => (
        <li key={i} onClick={() => handleSelected(item)} className={i === cursor ? "active" : ""}>
            <img src={"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/siamahnaf198/country-flags@main/img/" + item.countryCode + ".svg"} alt={item.country} width="20px" />
            <span className="simple-phone-input-sri198-dropdown-text">{item.country}</span>
            <span className="simple-phone-input-sri198-dropdown-country-code">{item.callingCode}</span>
        </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

But works perfectly. But problem is when I press on down key then whole window being scrolled. But I want to scroll only list element on keypress. Is it possible do only scroll ul tag area and select the list by keydown and keyup with enter press. Please help me. Actually it is a dropdown menu. Ul will open when a button clicked.

It is live url- https://test-eight-omega-89.vercel.app/

Comment: You have a list, but you use one variable to store the state of the entire list

Comment: Then what I have to change?

Comment: You need to have as many states as elements in the list. Or your state have to be an array

Comment: If you don't want the whole document to scroll when you press the down arrow, you probably need to call `e.preventDefault()` in your keypress handler. Just know that this is generally bad UX, to prevent normal expected behavior. So try to avoid it unless you have good reasons.

Comment: My state is an array. See the code.

Comment: I think it can done with ref but I not enough idea.